Issue with fancyhdr and headheight in MDPI template
Problem:
The MDPI template on Overleaf compiles with the following warning:
Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): Make it at least 20.0pt, 
for example: \setlength{\headheight}{20.0pt}. You might also make \topmargin smaller 
to compensate:(fancyhdr) \addtolength{\topmargin}{-8.0pt}.

Minimal Working Example (MWE)
A minimal working example is available here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/mdpi-article-template/fcpwsspfzsph
Potential solution:
A potential solution that I found out is to add the following line, but this pushes the entire layout down. I wish to solve the warning without having the layout moved.
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}

Desired solution:
To solve the warning, without having any changes done to the layout.

"following error": this is a warning, not an error

Please include a MWE in your question so that it remains useful to future users even if the link stops working.

Did you try to change the topmargin?

Don't stop reading the warning message after the \setlength command. Also read the explanation of the Warning message in section 17 page 22 of the fancyhdr manual and also option nocheck at the same place.

@cabohah Thanks, this solved it. I just added a negative topmargin to compensate.
